# How to remove non-API symbols from static library (.a/.lib)?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, visual-c++, abi

I want to pack an external library into my static library binary. But I'm afraid of user also has a different version of this external library.

I want to remove non-API symbols from the final produced lib to prevent user linking
to unwanted symbols from my lib. Is there any way to achieve it with MSVC and GNU toolchain?

I also heard about a technique called `Partial Linking` for GNU LD, which seems to be suitable to me. But I can't find any working examples for MSVC. Is it possible on MSVC?

It's not a problem related to common Symbol Visibility because the Symbol Visibility is only available on dynamic library. The question is for static library.

Comment: `static` keyword (C or C++) or anonymous namespaces (without a name) (C++ and equivalent to `static` in C++).

Comment: I've used partial linking in gnu ld - you end up with a .a containing a monolithic .o. It doesn't work consistently. I would build the third party library with it's own separate namespace and embed that, instead of using other tricks - it would most likely be an identical process on windows and linux also.

Comment: @Sahsahae `static` doesn't work if the internal function is used in more then one source file. Also these function must not be excluded from the symbol table. But: With appropriate compiler parameters a call to a function without a prototype should not compile. So simply don't have prototypes of internal functions in the headers that are published to the users of your library

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt `static`s by definition cannot be used in more than one "source file" unless you bundle them together into a single compilation unit in the first place. An alternative is to use visibility modifiers with -fvisibility=hidden by default so *all* symbols are removed unless specified otherwise. Not sure how that's done with MSVC.

Comment: @Sahsahae `-fvisibility=hidden` just limits the visibility after linkage and has no effect for static library. because static library is just a package of object files.